# How to access outer column values in mysql subquery?

Tags: mysql, select

In mysql I have this query

```
SELECT m.*
FROM members m
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 
                IF(`from member_id`=1, `to member_id`, `from member_id`) as other_id, text, `date sent`
             FROM message
             WHERE ((`from member_id`=1 AND `to member_id`=m.id) OR (`to member_id`=1 OR `from member_id`=m.id))
             ORDER BY `date sent` DESC
             LIMIT 1
            ) as t on 1=1
ORDER BY t.`date sent` DESC
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Unknown column 'm.id' in 'where clause'
```

How can I pass the members column value in the sub query select statement?

I am creating this sub query so it evaluates to 1 row, then I want to attach it to the right of the outer select statement.

Thanks.

Comment: Whose brilliant idea was it to put spaces in column names?

Comment: What is this mess of a query supposed to do? it can probably be simplified.

Comment: I figured out how to do it, apparently what I wanted is known as the `groupwise maximum`. A good example of it is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211479/groupwise-maximum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `SELECT` the `from member_id`/`to member_id` values in the subquery.  Then, you can join the table `m` on the derived table where you will have access to the values.

```
) as t on t.`from member_id` = 1 AND t.`to member_id` = m.id
OR t.`to member_id` = 1 OR t.`from member_id` = m.id
```