# How to retrieve the last record in each group

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I am trying to get data from my table using group by . using group by works correctly but i need to take only last inserted item of every group but its not work. my query always return first item of each group.

my query

```
SELECT id,type,userId,performDate,eventId FROM
`user_marker` where  `eventId`='842' and DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(performDate),'%Y%c%d')
=DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%c%d') 
 and `visibility`='1'GROUP BY type ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Groupwise maximum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211479/groupwise-maximum)

Comment: probably you can use 'limit 1' too

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
SELECT a.* FROM ( SELECT id,type,userId,performDate,eventId FROM 
`user_marker` where  `eventId`='842' and DATE_FORMAT(from_unixtime(performDate),'%Y%c%d')
=DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%c%d') and `visibility`='1' ORDER BY id DESC ) as a GROUP BY a.type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try as per below-

```
SELECT b.id,b.type,b.userId,b.performDate,b.eventId 
FROM user_marker b 
JOIN (SELECT `type`,MAX(performDate) 
FROM user_marker 
WHERE  `eventId`='842' AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(performDate))=CURDATE() AND `visibility`='1' 
GROUP BY `type`) a ON a.type=b.type AND a.performDate=b.performDate 
ORDER BY b.`type`;
```

Comment: thanks @Strawberry to draw my attention on it, actually I was checking unixtime format, if it convert in same mysql format, so that we can avoid one extra date_format functino.

Comment: Still missing that alias